# Creating sequence of alternating random sized circles

Tags: java, swing, graphics, computer-science

Need help fixing this.

I should be getting multiple distinguishable circles of different random sizes, however my program seems to just make too many circles until its filled up.

Here is what is expected:

[image: goal]

Here is what my program outputs:

[image: my code]

I have inputs (askDouble e.g.) that save the input into a variable. The height has to be less than PATTERN_SIZE which is 300.

the code:
constants:

```java
public static final double PATTERN_LEFT = 50.0;   // Left side of the pattern
public static final double PATTERN_TOP = 50.0;    // Top of the pattern
public static final double PATTERN_SIZE = 300.0;  // The size of the pattern on the window
```

method for drawing circles:

```java
/**
 * Drawing a sequence of circles.
 */
public void drawRandomCircles(){
    double height = 0;
    boolean validHeight = false;

    while(!validHeight){
        height = UI.askDouble("Enter height below 300px: ");

        if(height < PATTERN_SIZE && height > 0){
            validHeight = true;
            UI.setColor(Color.black);
            UI.drawRect(PATTERN_LEFT,PATTERN_TOP,PATTERN_SIZE,height);

        }

    }

    while(validHeight){
        double circleSize = (3 * Math.random() * (height-3));
        UI.setColor(Color.blue);
        for(int i = 0; i < circleSize; i++){
            if(circleSize < height){
                UI.fillOval(PATTERN_LEFT + i,PATTERN_TOP,circleSize,circleSize);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I know I have to have at least 2 while loops for the question as I've been told so. Any help in the right direction will be appreciated. I'm guessing it could be needing new variables for the second while loop's conditions as it just keeps drawing heaps of circles lol.

Comment: i suggest to create another method to drawCircle(centerCoord, radius), then your drawRandomCircles() should randomized the radius, and set the new centerCoord X= previous centerCoord X+ random radius + 1. 

And of course the radius must not be greater than height/2

Comment: Your question to the user should not be in a loop. Get the input then set off a Swing `Timer` until the window is filled. You might keep your circles in `List<Shape>`. If you want the user to keep choosing then it's a bit different but the `Timer` should probably still be used.

Answer (score 0):

Your code uses a UI class that we don't have access to.

This solution is written in generic Java Swing.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.

Here's the GUI I came up with.

[image: Random Circles]

The first thing I did was create a `Circle` class.  The `Circle` class is a plain Java getter/setter class that holds a radius and a center point.  I prefer dealing with a center point when drawing circles, rather than the upper left corner of the bounding rectangle.  I used a `java.awt.Point` instance to hold the center point.

Next, I created a `RandomCirclesModel` class.  The `RandomCirclesModel` class is a plain Java getter/setter class that holds a `java.util.List` of `Circle` instances, the dimensions of the drawing `JPanel`, and a margin.  When I create a drawing `JPanel`, I like to have a margin around the drawing area.  Since the number of circles is random, I use a `List` to store all the circles.

I calculate all of the `Circle` instances before I draw anything.  The last "random" circle has to have a radius that just makes it fit in the bounding rectangle.

I'm not going to discuss the Java Swing code since you have that secret UI class.

The `Circle` instances are calculated in the `ButtonListener` class.  The `actionPerformed` method determines if the maximum diameter is in the range.  I set a minimum diameter of 50 pixels and your maximum diameter of 300 pixels.  The `calculateRandomCircles` method calculates the random circles.  Naming methods are that easy.  Verb-noun combinations.

Here's the complete runnable code.  I made the additional classes inner classes so I could post this code as one block.

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class RandomCirclesGUI implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new RandomCirclesGUI());
    }

    private final RandomCirclesModel model;

    private final DrawingPanel drawingPanel;

    private JTextField validHeightField;

    public RandomCirclesGUI() {
        this.model = new RandomCirclesModel();
        this.drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel(model);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Random Circles");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(createEntryPanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(drawingPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createEntryPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 5, 5, 5));

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Enter height below 300px:");
        panel.add(label);

        validHeightField = new JTextField(10);
        panel.add(validHeightField);

        panel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(30));

        JButton button = new JButton("Submit");
        button.addActionListener(new ButtonListener(this, model));
        panel.add(button);

        return panel;
    }

    public String getValidHeightField() {
        return validHeightField.getText();
    }

    public void repaint() {
        drawingPanel.repaint();
    }

    public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private final RandomCirclesModel model;

        public DrawingPanel(RandomCirclesModel model) {
            this.model = model;
            this.setPreferredSize(model.getDrawingPanelDimension());
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

            int width = getWidth();
            int height = model.getValidHeight();
            int margin = model.getMargin();

            paintBorder(g2d, width, height, margin);
            paintCircles(g2d);
        }

        private void paintBorder(Graphics2D g2d, int width, int height,
                int margin) {
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3f));
            g2d.drawLine(margin, margin, width - margin, margin);
            g2d.drawLine(margin, margin, margin, height - margin);
            g2d.drawLine(width - margin, margin, width - margin,
                    height - margin);
            g2d.drawLine(margin, height - margin, width - margin,
                    height - margin);
        }

        private void paintCircles(Graphics2D g2d) {
            g2d.setColor(Color.blue);
            for (Circle circle : model.getCircles()) {
                Point centerPoint = circle.getCenterPoint();
                int radius = circle.getRadius();
                int diameter = radius + radius;
                g2d.fillOval(centerPoint.x - radius, centerPoint.y - radius,
                        diameter, diameter);
            }
        }
    }

    public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

        private final RandomCirclesGUI view;

        private final RandomCirclesModel model;

        public ButtonListener(RandomCirclesGUI view, RandomCirclesModel model) {
            this.view = view;
            this.model = model;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            String text = view.getValidHeightField();
            double validHeightD;
            try {
                validHeightD = Double.valueOf(text);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                // Invalid value, return
                return;
            }

            int validHeight = (int) Math.round(validHeightD);
            int margin = model.getMargin();
            int width = model.getDrawingPanelDimension().width;
            int height = model.getDrawingPanelDimension().height;
            if (validHeight > 50 && validHeight <= height - margin - margin) {
                model.clearCircles();
                model.setValidHeight(validHeight);
                calculateRandomCircles(margin, width, validHeight);
                view.repaint();
            }
        }

        private void calculateRandomCircles(int margin, int width,
                int validHeight) {
            Random random = new Random();
            int x = margin;
            int y = validHeight / 2;
            while (x < (width - margin)) {
                int radius = random
                        .nextInt((validHeight - margin - margin) / 2);
                if (x > (width - margin - radius - radius)) {
                    radius = (width - margin - x) / 2;
                }
                x += radius;
                model.addCircle(new Circle(new Point(x, y), radius));
                x += radius;
            }
        }

    }

    public class RandomCirclesModel {

        private final int margin;
        private int validHeight;

        private final Dimension drawingPanelDimension;

        private final List<Circle> circles;

        public RandomCirclesModel() {
            this.margin = 10;
            this.validHeight = 320;
            this.drawingPanelDimension = new Dimension(820, validHeight);
            this.circles = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        public void clearCircles() {
            this.circles.clear();
        }

        public void addCircle(Circle circle) {
            this.circles.add(circle);
        }

        public void setValidHeight(int validHeight) {
            this.validHeight = validHeight;
        }

        public int getValidHeight() {
            return validHeight;
        }

        public int getMargin() {
            return margin;
        }

        public Dimension getDrawingPanelDimension() {
            return drawingPanelDimension;
        }

        public List<Circle> getCircles() {
            return circles;
        }

    }

    public class Circle {

        private final int radius;

        private final Point centerPoint;

        public Circle(Point centerPoint, int radius) {
            this.centerPoint = centerPoint;
            this.radius = radius;
        }

        public int getRadius() {
            return radius;
        }

        public Point getCenterPoint() {
            return centerPoint;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Nice. You might want to flag up `if (validHeight > 50 && validHeight <= height - margin - margin)` I put in 30 and nothing happened. Personally I think it would be more interesting if there were an animation with each circle being drawn successively in a viewable time frame. Antialiasing would be nicer

Comment: @g00se: I didn't write error messages because I was trying to keep the code as simple as I could.  The OP has a super secret UI class that builds most of the GUI.  You have the source code, you can create the drawing animation :-).

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc:  thanks very much for taking the time. It is an introductory programming class that is meant to be 12 weeks spaced into 6, so this is second/third week in, I have learnt normal Java syntax previously though but definitely makes the GUI ALOT easier ahah. Will have a look through this and see how I can implement the UI class into this. Cheers